Statically sized array with union parameter
I have an utility to create a statically sized array:
export type StaticArray<T, L extends number, R extends any[] = []> = R extends {
  length: L;
}
  ? R
  : StaticArray<T, L, [...R, T]>;

I can verify it works:
let myVar: StaticArray<number, 3>;
//  ^? let myVar: [number, number, number]

However, I want to make it work with sum types, but I'm not sure how it's possible. I would love this case to have that result:
let myVar: StaticArray<number, 3 | 2 | 1>;
//  ^? let myVar: [number, number, number] | [number, number] | [number]

But I doesn't seem to work, since my StaticArray type stops at the smallest number it sees.

Make it distribute over L right at the start; wrap the whole thing in L extends any ?…: never. I’ll demo when I get off mobile if nobody else does first

@jcalz I must admit I'm not familiar with distribution rules. My C++ template metaprogramming skills are of no help here :'(

@GuillaumeRacicot: jcalz refers to TypeScript Distributive Conditional Types

Just got to a real computer; I was saying do it this way. Does that meet your needs? If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes! It works. It honestly looks like magic to me though, care to explain why it works?

I will, when I get a chance. It might not be until tomorrow (it's my bedtime now)

You're saying that you want StaticArray<T, L> to distribute over unions in L, so that StaticArray<T, L1 | L2> is equivalent to StaticArray<T, L1> | StaticArray<T, L2>.
The general way to do this is to use a distributive conditional type.  When you write a conditional type of the form T extends U ? V : W where T is a generic type parameter, TypeScript will automatically distribute over unions in T.  If all you want is to turn a non-distributive type into a distributive one, you can wrap it with a "no-op" distributive conditional type like T extends any ? ⋯ : never. That looks like it does nothing (T always extends any) but it has the effect of distributing over unions.
So that leads us to write
type StaticArray<T, L extends number, R extends any[] = []> =
  L extends any ? R extends { length: L; } ? R : StaticArray<T, L, [...R, T]> : never;

and you can see that it works as desired:
let myVar: StaticArray<number, 3>;
//  ^? let myVar: [number, number, number]

let myVar2: StaticArray<number, 3 | 2 | 1>;
//  ^? let myVar2: [number] | [number, number] | [number, number, number]

Note that the any in T extends any ? ⋯ : never can be replaced with anything were you're sure T will extend it.  You can use unknown, or T, or some constraint (like number for L), depending on your preferences.
Playground link to code
